# Getting "Could not load file or assembly "MvcApplication1" with a fresh empty MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, runtime-error, .net-assembly

I finally switched from 32 bit Windows 7 to 64 bit Windows 7. When I try to run a fresh ASP.NET MVC application, I get this error:

`Could not load file or assembly MvcApplication1 or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.`

If I look at the bin folder I can see these files created:

```
`MvcApplication1.dll`
`MvcApplication1.pdb`
```

I've never run into such an error before in 32bit environment.

The version of MVC is 4. Besides that, I don't have such a problem with a console application.

Comment: Do you reference your MVC Application to other app? Or solution contains just this MVC application?

Comment: No, I don't reference anything. It's a blank MVC application. I run it as soon as it's created

Comment: Did you check your references of MVC app? All references are ok?

Comment: In fact I understand what you mean, but how do I check that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. I'd selected x64 for Target platform. After changing it to Any CPU, the problem evaporated.